# In python, reading multiple CSV's, with different headers, into one dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, netcdf

I have dozens of csv files with similar (but not always exactly the same) headers. For instance, one has:

```
Year Month Day Hour Minute Direct Diffuse D_Global D_IR Zenith Test_Site
```

One has:

```
Year Month Day Hour Minute Direct Diffuse2 D_Global D_IR U_Global U_IR Zenith Test_Site
```

(Notice one lacks "U_Global" and "U_IR", the other has "Diffuse2" instead of "Diffuse")

I know how to pass multiple csv's into my script, but how do I have the csv's only pass values to columns in which they currently have values? And perhaps pass "Nan" to all other columns in that row.

Ideally I'd have something like:

```
'Year','Month','Day','Hour','Minute','Direct','Diffuse','Diffuse2','D_Global','D_IR','U_Global','U_IR','Zenith','Test_Site'
1992,1,1,0,3,-999.00,-999.00,"Nan",-999.00,-999.00,"Nan","Nan",122.517,"BER"
2013,5,30,15,55,812.84,270.62,"Nan",1078.06,-999.00,"Nan","Nan",11.542,"BER"
2004,9,1,0,1,1.04,79.40,"Nan",78.67,303.58,61.06,310.95,85.142,"ALT"
2014,12,1,0,1,0.00,0.00,"Nan",-999.00,226.95,0.00,230.16,115.410,"ALT"
```

The other caveat, is that this dataframe needs to be appended to. It needs to remain as multiple csv files are passed into it. I think I'll probably have it write out to it's own csv at the end (it's eventually going to NETCDF4).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have the following CSV files:

test1.csv:

```
year,month,day,Direct 
1992,1,1,11
2013,5,30,11
2004,9,1,11
```

test2.csv:

```
year,month,day,Direct,Direct2
1992,1,1,21,201
2013,5,30,21,202
2004,9,1,21,203
```

test3.csv:

```
year,month,day,File3
1992,1,1,text1
2013,5,30,text2
2004,9,1,text3
2016,1,1,unmatching_date
```

**Solution:**

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

files = glob.glob(r'd:/temp/test*.csv')

def get_merged(files, **kwargs):
    df = pd.read_csv(files[0], **kwargs)
    for f in files[1:]:
        df = df.merge(pd.read_csv(f, **kwargs), how='outer')
    return df

print(get_merged(files))
```

**Output:**

```
   year  month  day  Direct   Direct  Direct2            File3
0  1992      1    1     11.0    21.0    201.0            text1
1  2013      5   30     11.0    21.0    202.0            text2
2  2004      9    1     11.0    21.0    203.0            text3
3  2016      1    1      NaN     NaN      NaN  unmatching_date
```

**UPDATE:** usual idiomatic `pd.concat(list_of_dfs)` solution wouldn't work here, because it's joining by indexes:

```
In [192]: pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in glob.glob(file_mask)], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
Out[192]:
   Direct  Direct   Direct2            File3  day  month  year
0     NaN     11.0      NaN              NaN    1      1  1992
1     NaN     11.0      NaN              NaN   30      5  2013
2     NaN     11.0      NaN              NaN    1      9  2004
3    21.0      NaN    201.0              NaN    1      1  1992
4    21.0      NaN    202.0              NaN   30      5  2013
5    21.0      NaN    203.0              NaN    1      9  2004
6     NaN      NaN      NaN            text1    1      1  1992
7     NaN      NaN      NaN            text2   30      5  2013
8     NaN      NaN      NaN            text3    1      9  2004
9     NaN      NaN      NaN  unmatching_date    1      1  2016

In [193]: pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in glob.glob(file_mask)], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
Out[193]:
       0    1     2     3       4    5     6     7      8     9   10  11               12
0  1992.0  1.0   1.0  11.0  1992.0  1.0   1.0  21.0  201.0  1992   1   1            text1
1  2013.0  5.0  30.0  11.0  2013.0  5.0  30.0  21.0  202.0  2013   5  30            text2
2  2004.0  9.0   1.0  11.0  2004.0  9.0   1.0  21.0  203.0  2004   9   1            text3
3     NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN  2016   1   1  unmatching_date
```

or using `index_col=None` explicitly:

```
In [194]: pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, index_col=None) for f in glob.glob(file_mask)], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
Out[194]:
   Direct  Direct   Direct2            File3  day  month  year
0     NaN     11.0      NaN              NaN    1      1  1992
1     NaN     11.0      NaN              NaN   30      5  2013
2     NaN     11.0      NaN              NaN    1      9  2004
3    21.0      NaN    201.0              NaN    1      1  1992
4    21.0      NaN    202.0              NaN   30      5  2013
5    21.0      NaN    203.0              NaN    1      9  2004
6     NaN      NaN      NaN            text1    1      1  1992
7     NaN      NaN      NaN            text2   30      5  2013
8     NaN      NaN      NaN            text3    1      9  2004
9     NaN      NaN      NaN  unmatching_date    1      1  2016

In [195]: pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, index_col=None) for f in glob.glob(file_mask)], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
Out[195]:
       0    1     2     3       4    5     6     7      8     9   10  11               12
0  1992.0  1.0   1.0  11.0  1992.0  1.0   1.0  21.0  201.0  1992   1   1            text1
1  2013.0  5.0  30.0  11.0  2013.0  5.0  30.0  21.0  202.0  2013   5  30            text2
2  2004.0  9.0   1.0  11.0  2004.0  9.0   1.0  21.0  203.0  2004   9   1            text3
3     NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN  2016   1   1  unmatching_date
```

The following more idiomatic solution works, **but** it changes original order of columns and rows / data:

```
In [224]: dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, index_col=None) for f in glob.glob(r'd:/temp/test*.csv')]
     ...:
     ...: common_cols = list(set.intersection(*[set(x.columns.tolist()) for x in dfs]))
     ...:
     ...: pd.concat((df.set_index(common_cols) for df in dfs), axis=1).reset_index()
     ...:
Out[224]:
   month  day  year  Direct   Direct  Direct2            File3
0      1    1  1992     11.0    21.0    201.0            text1
1      1    1  2016      NaN     NaN      NaN  unmatching_date
2      5   30  2013     11.0    21.0    202.0            text2
3      9    1  2004     11.0    21.0    203.0            text3
```

Comment: don't use merge like this is non idiomatic and non performant here - append to a list and concat is the pattern

Comment: @Jeff, how would i merge on common columns using `concat`?

Comment: try it, by definition it will union in the non concat axes; joining is a different operation

Comment: I tested it before answering - that was actually my first idea... It "duplicates" all common columns if i use `axis=1`

Comment: you want axis=0; append by rows

Comment: @jeff, no, OP wants `axis=1` - look at their desired data set

Comment: just try it and u will see; this is a very common pattern

Comment: @Jeff, please see UPDATE - i don't think OP wanted something like this...

Comment: you need to ignore_index=True

Comment: it's exactly as the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-using-append

Comment: you are setting the index with the first column

Comment: no, i'm not setting it. `index_col=None` is default if it's omitted, anyway i've added this version - UPDATE2

Comment: no it's NOT the default; not really sure what you are doing wrong then - this is the correct pattern

Comment: @Jeff, OP wants to __merge__ (equivalent to SQL join or outer join) 3+ DFs on common columns, i don't think we can use `concat` here...

Comment: hmm maybe this is a merge problem / my quick look showed disjoint data ; if that's not the case then merging for is the answer then

Comment: @Jeff, sorry to bother you - one more question: why did you say `index_col=None` is NOT default for `pd.read_csv()` - is the docstring incorrect then?

Comment: sorry that was a typo

Comment: Can't you replace `[pd.read_csv(f) for f in glob.glob(file_mask)]` by `(pd.read_csv(f) for f in glob.glob(file_mask))`, making it load the files iteratively

Comment: @MaartenFabré, i've changed it, but i'm not sure how it'll help

Comment: like that the interpreter doesn't have to hold all of the csv's in memory just to create the list. a generator is more efficient if an iterable is enough

Answer (score 4):

Can't pandas take care of this automagically?

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-using-append

If your indices overlap, don't forget to add 'ignore_index=True'

Comment: actually, append will merge DFs differently (compared to what OP wants)...

Answer (score 1):

First, run through all the files to define the common headers :

```
csv_path = './csv_files'
csv_separator = ','

full_headers = []
for fn in os.listdir(csv_path):
    with open(fn, 'r') as f:
        headers = f.readline().split(csv_separator)
        full_headers += full_headers + list(set(full_headers) - set(headers))
```

Then write your header line into your output file, and run again through all the files to fill it.

You can use : `csv.DictReader(open('myfile.csv'))` to be able to match the headers to their designated column simply.